# TikiWiki or similar with php 4

Tags: content-management-system, wiki, php4

I'm looking for content management system/framework to build a website which has some (more or less) static pages, an events calendar and a wiki section, possible adding a forum at some point.  The best I've found is TikiWiki, but my host (which I can't change) is still using php 4.  Anyone have any other suggestions?  I'm not bothered about general site design/themes (in fact I'd prefer to do that myself), just something to manage the back end.  Been thinking about writing it myself, maybe using something like codeigniter, or cobbling together a couple of different cms's, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Why can't you change the host?

Comment: Hosted on a university server and they refuse to be anything like up-to-date!

Answer (score 0):

Old releases of [DokuWiki](http://dokuwiki.org/) (<= 2009-02-14b) work with PHP 4. There are many plugins for DokuWiki that may implement the functionality and writing your own plugins is a snap.

[Drupal 6](http://drupal.org/) may also be a good option.

Be prepared for lots and lots of errors, cursing and backporting work when using plugins. PHP 4 is officially "dead" for two years now.

Comment: Thanks, think I'm going to do it a different way now anyway.  The guy I'm designing the site for has decided he doesn't need so much flexibility.